# How to correct WinAPI calls?

Tags: winapi

Last time I described my problem badly.
Now I'll try to explain my problem clearer.

I'm trying to make HDD serial checking to prevent distribution of the program. I don't have its src, so I found some space in `.code` section and injected code there.

[image: Screenshot]

You can see intermodular calls. For example, `call kernel32.GetDriveTypeA` matches `call 75738D98`. BUT after reboot this address changes. However my code calls incorrect `75738D98` address.

I need to fix it (resolve new `GetDriveTypeA` address and replace `75738D98` with correct address)

Comment: Modern versions of Windows will randomize the base addresses of loaded modules to make it more difficult to implement "return-to-libc" attacks.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: You should have edited your previous question, instead of reformulating in a new one. Now just delete the previous question, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` will give you the address to a DLL function. The next natural question is: how can you call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` if you don't know their address?

All user processes have kernel32 loaded. You don't need to dynamically load anything in kernel32.

*Normally* your linker & the OS loader does this all for you by linking to an import library (kernel32.lib for example). This will tell the OS that you want kernel32 loaded with your DLL. Your DLL has a [import address table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Import_Table) which contains a bunch of stubs to the real imported functions. When your module is loaded, the OS patches these stubs to point to the real function address.

You should probably be doing it this way too. Your app can even be detected as malware if you try to get too hackery.

Do you have a good reason not to just link to the import lib?

Comment: No, the linker produces a stub which is hooked up by the OS loader code when the DLL is mapped into memory.

Comment: Then continuing: how can *that* stub be modified?

Comment: A better question is: Why assume it should stay the same? It's virtual address space; you should not assume the location of any modules. That's why LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress exist.

Comment: The code on disk stays the same. The code in memory (the import address table) is patched. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Import_Table

Comment: Thx, tenfour! Fortunately, target PE has `GetProcAddress` in its import table! Now I should only call them and get right address of ant fuction.